# How to import icons from tailwind correctly into vue array

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, tailwind-css, vite, vue-composition-api

I have an array of objects that contains the info about every picture I need to add on the main page (with *v-for*) . I use Tailwind and its Heroicons. But I don't know how to add icons to the array correctly.
This is  **picturesData.ts**

```
import {AcademicCapIcon, ClockIcon, MailIcon } from  '@heroicons/vue/outline'
const picturesData = [
    {
      img: "image1",
      title: "education",
      src: "education.jpg",
      subtitle: "Because we are all students",
      icon: <AcademicCapIcon />,
    },
    {
      img: "image2",
      title: "recreational",
      src: "recreation.jpg",
      subtitle: "Who doesn't like having fun?",
      icon: <ClockIcon/>      
    },
    {
      img: "image3",
      title: "social",
      src: "social.jpg",
      subtitle: "Need some friends?",
      icon: <MailIcon/>      
    },];
  export default picturesData;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the list define only the component name as string :

```js
const picturesData = [
    {
      img: "image1",
      title: "education",
      src: "education.jpg",
      subtitle: "Because we are all students",
      icon: "AcademicCapIcon",
    },
 ...
```

then in your components import and register the component and use `<component :is="icon"/>` to render them :

```html
   <div v-for="pic in pictureData" >
     <component :is="pic.icon"/>
....
import {AcademicCapIcon, ClockIcon, MailIcon } from  '@heroicons/vue/outline'

export default defineComponent({
 components:{AcademicCapIcon, ClockIcon, MailIcon}
...
})
```

in script setup syntax just import them :

```html
<script setup>
import {AcademicCapIcon, ClockIcon, MailIcon } from  '@heroicons/vue/outline'
</script>
```

Comment: What's the Vue 3 composition API equivalent for this?

Comment: do you mean script setup?

Comment: Yes indeed. The script setup.

Comment: @studio-pj please check my edited answer